# object is undefined, don't know why

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"
I'd be glad if you could help me debug it:

```
var TWITTER = '"twitter"';
var FECEBOOK = '"facebook"';
var FACEBOOKicon = "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/yi/r/q9U99v3_saj.ico";
var TWITTERicon = "https://twitter.com/phoenix/favicon.ico";

var tweetlinks;
tweetlinks = document.querySelectorAll('[href*=' + TWITTER + ']');
var facelinks;
facelinks = document.querySelectorAll('[href*=' + FECEBOOK + ']');

function getLinks() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= tweetlinks.length; i++) {
        setBackground(tweetlinks[i], TWITTERicon);
    }

    for (var g = 0; i <= facelinks.length; g++) {
        setBackground(facelinks[g], FACEBOOKicon);
    }    

    function setBackground(elment, backimage) {
        elment.style.backgroundImage = backimage;
    }
}

getLinks();
```

Comment: I can't iterate over `tweetlinks` and `facelinks` even when they are not empty...

Comment: You have a typo: elment -> element (but this is not the source of any issues). And you have another typo: FECEBOOK -> FACEBOOK (I wouldn't want to read that book!)

Comment: Perhaps "elment" is supposed to be a real variable "element"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ates and Frederic both posted problems in the code. You'll need to see to both for your code to work:

```
var TWITTER = '"twitter"';
var FECEBOOK = '"facebook"';
var FACEBOOKicon = "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/yi/r/q9U99v3_saj.ico";
var TWITTERicon = "https://twitter.com/phoenix/favicon.ico";

var tweetlinks;
tweetlinks = document.querySelectorAll('[href*=' + TWITTER + ']');
var facelinks;
facelinks = document.querySelectorAll('[href*=' + FECEBOOK + ']');

function getLinks() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tweetlinks.length; i++) {
        setBackground(tweetlinks[i], TWITTERicon);
    }

    for (var g = 0; g < facelinks.length; g++) {
        setBackground(facelinks[g], FACEBOOKicon);
    }    

    function setBackground(elment, backimage) {
        elment.style.backgroundImage = backimage;
    }
}

getLinks();
```

The reason you use `i < arr.length` instead of `i <= arr.length` is because arrays are indexed at zero, meaning that the first element is at index 0, even though we call it the *first* element. If we have an array `['a', 'b', 'c']`, it has three elements, but the *third* element is at index 2.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
i <= tweetlinks.length
```

To:

```
i < tweetlinks.length
```

Your loops are going beyond the arrays, resulting in an undefined value in the last iterations. Array indices range from 0 to length - 1, and not 0 to length.

Answer (score 2):

There are various bugs in your code. First: you don't want to loop from 0 to <= .length but to < .length. Second, in the second loop you use g as a counter variable, but compare to i.

Answer (score 2):

There are mismatched loop variables in your code. You should write:

```
for (var g = 0; g < facelinks.length; g++) {
    setBackground(facelinks[g], FACEBOOKicon);
}
```

Instead of:

```
for (var g = 0; i <= facelinks.length; g++) {
    setBackground(facelinks[g], FACEBOOKicon);
}
```

Also, all the comparisons to `length` in your `for` loops should be `strictly less than` (`<`) instead of `less than or equal to` (`<=`), since array indexes are zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you checked what is it you are *really* getting in variables:
tweetlinks and facelinks?

It appears to me that you are setting the "style" property of an "undefined" object.
Perhaps you are not getting what you are expecting in those arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typing mistake. instead of "elment", it should be "element".

Comment: this should be a comment

Answer (score -1):

It looks like in your `setBackground` function, `elment` is undefined or null or nothing as they say. This can be because you are going over the index via your for loop. Change:

```
i <= facelinks.length
```

To:

```
i < facelinks.length
```